# js slider does not work on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have js fiddle which works fine,

I tried to replicate it on my local system, where slider(menu icon) neither appears nor works. Here is my jsfiddle and source code, can anyone tell me what I missed.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/nzxd5r3r/10/

source code on local system:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>Starter Template - Materialize</title>

        <!--<link href="font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.ttf" rel="stylesheet">-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>

        <script>
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
            $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
            $('.button-collapse').sideNav({menuWidth: 240, activationWidth: 70});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
             <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
             <nav>
                  <div class="nav-wrapper light-blue lighten-1">
                    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="full side-nav">

                        <li><a href="#">John Daglas</a>
                          <ul class="collection">
                            <li class="collection-item avatar">
                              <img src="http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/dog/dog-05.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
                              <span class="title">Title</span>
                              <p>First Line <br>
                                 Second Line
                              </p>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Follower analysis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tweet analysis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Retweet analysis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tweet analysis</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Include this line below -->
                    <a class="button-collapse" href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
                    <!-- End -->

                  </div>
            </nav>
    <div class="row scrollspy grey lighten-4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s2 m2">
                        <div class="card-panel green accent-4">
                          <span class="white-text">Tweets
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s2 m2 ">
                        <div class="card-panel deep-orange accent-2">
                             <i class="material-icons">repeat</i>
                          <span class="white-text">Retweet
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s2 m2">
                        <div class="card-panel green accent-4">
                          <span class="white-text"> Favourite
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s2 m2 ">
                        <div class="card-panel deep-orange accent-2">
                          <span class="white-text"> Followers
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s2 m2">
                        <div class="card-panel green accent-4">
                          <span class="white-text"> Sentiment
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s2 m2 ">
                        <div class="card-panel deep-orange accent-2">
                          <span class="white-text"> Social score
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s6 m6">
                        <div class="card-panel teal">
                          <span class="white-text">Sentiment analysis graph for tweets
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6 m6">
                        <div class="card-panel light-blue accent-4">
                          <span class="white-text">Sentiment analysis donuts graph for all hastags
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m12">
                        <div class="card-panel teal">
                          <span class="white-text">Tags analysis.
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="page-footer">
            <div class="footer-copyright">
                <div class="container">© 2014 Copyright Text <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why aren't all the script tags in the `<head>`? It looks like there are some stragglers at the end of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait until the DOM has been initialized (document has been fully loaded). Wrap your slider code in something like this:

```
$(function() {
    //code
});
```

Also, you're using an old version of jQuery in the code you posted which is incompatible with Materialize.js. Please use the latest version of jQuery 1.x (check here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)

Comment: @Jai Thanks for the catch

Comment: @AdamMazzarella: still facing same issue

Comment: @user2129623 Open the developer console in your browser (usually F12) and let me know if there are any errors reported on the "Console" tab.

Comment: @AdamMazzarella: thanks, I can not see any error in console, well when I minized my screen to see console, I could see icon to click to open slider, but when I maximize, it disappears. Also when I click nothing happens

Comment: I've got it, you're using an old version of jQuery in your local code. Please use the latest 1.x version: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js`. The first reason things weren't working correctly is because `$.on()` was not implemented prior to v1.7 and Materialize was trying to use this to bind elements.